# "Word" tag -- useful?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There are currently 20 posts tagged *word*.  Is this tag useful?  Most of the questions seem to be word-choice (a tag I created and am not crazy about -- the idea is right, but I don't like the term) or etymology questions.  Any reason *not* to retag them all to something less generic?

EDIT (Dec '11) - I don't suppose there have been any "word" tags for a long time, but I wouldn't want to see this question closed/deleted. It's a useful template for others that might turn up.

Answer (score 10):

Retag away. [word] is way too general to be useful--questions with that tag should be retagged [word-choice], [etymology], [usage], etc. as appropriate.