# List of tags that are blacklisted, burninated or under discussion

Tags: discussion, tags

I had a look at the meta discussions that are about burninating, blacklisting/deleting or creating tags. I made a list of them. Why? It's for two purposes. Firstly, to have an overview about our taxonomy efforts besides [tag synonyms](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms). Secondly to track reappearing tags that have been burninated by community consensus before. Since the second is a lot more important those are at the top.

Why is the second more important? It is important because it gives us a reason to put them onto the blacklist if they pop up again.

There are just rhetoric questions so far you say? Yes there are. ***What I want and hope this helps to do*** is keeping tabs on burninated tags and squashing resurrecting ones in their tracks. If one detects a resurfaced tag the - hopefully few - questions can be edited and the date added to the burninated tag. If there are several dates behind a tag we can request a blacklisting.

**Burninated but doesn't stay dead**

- [word-games](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-games) ([On tag:scrabble, tag:word-games, tag:games](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1588)) - 15 questions

**Decent votes but no burnination completed yet**

- [obscure-terms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/obscure-terms) ([What's the tag "obscure-terms" for? Is it necessary?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9461)) - 38 questions
- [homework](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) ([Is the "homework" tag really useful? Is there a way to vote to delete it?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2099/191178)) - 45 questions

**Disputed**

- [explanation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/explanation) ([Can someone explain the [explanation] tag to me?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7601))
- [expression-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expression-requests), [phrase-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-requests), [idiom-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idiom-requests) ([What are [expression-requests] tag for?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7871))
- [nuance](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nuance) ([Do we need [tag:nuance]?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1367))
- [typography](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typography) ([Are typography questions on-topic or off-topic?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/908))
- [usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage) ([Does the "usage" tag have any value?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30) & [Is there a difference between [usage] and [word-usage]?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4643))
- [word-usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-usage) ([Is there a difference between [usage] and [word-usage]?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4643))
- [request](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/request) & [polite-request](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polite-request) ([Burninate tags [request] and [polite-request]](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9419))
- [books](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) & [literature](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/literature) ([Is "Literature" a pointless tag?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2871))
- [vocabulary](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulary) ([Is the vocabulary tag helpful?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9391))

**Tags validated by meta discussion**

- [single-word-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests) ([Against single word requests](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1654))
- [title](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/title) ([What manner of “title”?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5473))
- [writing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing) ([Is the tag "writing" necessary?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209))

### Blacklisted or burninated by community consensus

**Blacklisted tags**

The system prevents the use of blacklisted tags.

- [language](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) ([Should the 'language' tag be deleted?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9409))
- [english](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english) ([How about getting rid of the [english] tag?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/625))
- [words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/words) ([Blacklist the [words] tag](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1053/blacklist-the-words-tag))
- [word](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word) (["Word" tag -- useful?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140)) Synonym of words actually

**Burninated tags**

- [acceptability](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acceptability) ([Tag for questions about whether a language feature is acceptable/common?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320)) - Removed again 09.10.2016
- [correction](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/correction) ([Let's get rid of the "correction" tag](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9618))
- [descriptivism](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/descriptivism) ([What is the meaning of the descriptivism tag?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2402))
- [essay](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/essay) ([Should we delete the essay tag?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6841))
- [genericized-trademarks](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genericized-trademarks)
- [ic](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ic) ([Delete the [wish], [harry-potter], and other tags?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3843))
- [ian](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ian) ([Delete the [wish], [harry-potter], and other tags?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3843))
- [games](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/games) ([On tag:scrabble, tag:word-games, tag:games](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1588))  - Removed again 13.10.2016
- [grammar-checker](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar-checker) ([What should be done with the "grammar-checker" tag?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/862))
- [harry-potter](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) ([Delete the [wish], [harry-potter], and other tags?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3843))
- [management-speak](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/management-speak) ([Delete the [wish], [harry-potter], and other tags?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3843))
  ([Delete the [wish], [harry-potter], and other tags?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3843))
- [microsoft-word](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word) ([What is the point of the Microsoft-Word tag?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9491))
- [opinion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opinion) ([Burninate [opinion], please](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7885))
- [pedantic](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pedantic) ([Delete [pedantic] tag](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2169))
- [polisemy](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polisemy) ([Delete the [wish], [harry-potter], and other tags?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3843))
- [productiveness](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/productiveness) ([Delete the [wish], [harry-potter], and other tags?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3843))
- [proofreading](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proofreading) ([Proof-reading tag: what to do with it?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6763))
- [puzzle](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle) ([Delete [puzzle] tag](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2522))
- [scrabble](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrabble) ([On tag:scrabble, tag:word-games, tag:games](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1588)) - Removed again 07.10.2016
- [sexist-language](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sexist-language) ([Creating the new tag "sexist-language"](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3930)) [Creation discussion at -10 & removed by SE moderator at the time] - Removed again 10.10.2016
- [similarities](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/similarities), [similar](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/similar) ([Should we get rid of the tag "similarities"?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7778))
- [spelling-checker](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spelling-checker) ([Should we burninate the [spelling-checker] tag? (0 posts left tagged)](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9507))
- [tech-speak](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tech-speak) ([Delete the [wish], [harry-potter], and other tags?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3843))
- [wish](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wish) ([Delete the [wish], [harry-potter], and other tags?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3843))

Comment: @DanBron no, burnination does not include blacklisting. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120642/338924

Comment: Ah! Ok, comment withdrawn.

Comment: re [tag:sexist-language]: should be replaced as needed by [tag:gender]

Comment: @Mitch that one was actually not as black and white. I think I used at last *connotation*, *offensive-language*, *pejorative-language*, *gender* and outright deletion. :) Generally the questions were all over the place.

Comment: My point was that something about sex would have been god to leave in. In fact, I can't remember what the question was about and have no idea how to find it again except that it had something to do with gender. Since there's no tag at all to that effect, I'm out of luck.

Comment: @Mitch those thirteen questions had no common nominator besides the arbitrarily used tag. If it was about grammatical-gender I tagged it as such.  Anything with sexual undertones went either to connotations or pejorative-language.

Comment: Now let's burninate [tag:games], (or maybe even blacklist it.)

Comment: @nvz it will be deleted by the nightly roomba

Comment: I'd love to hear what the down vote on this overview is for.